# How to develop responsive layer container in Leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, resize, layer, bounds

I'm using leaflet.js to develop a drawing layer tool with the full-page map. Users will draw a group of layers to describe an industrial product's parts.

The leaflet map and its layers should be fit to screen. For example, if a user draws a circle to the left bottom corner with 1920x1080 resolution pc, I should see it in the left bottom corner with my 1366x768 resolution pc. The leaflet map is resizing with the page correctly but the circle is being out of the screen in my pc because of its latitude-longitude in this example.

I tried to develop this example with invalidateSize, maxBounds, fitBounds, etc. but haven't succeeded yet. How can I develop this scenario?

Saved GeoJSON from 1920x1080 with layers looking:
[image]

Loaded same GeoJSON from 1366x768 looking (attention to left corner):
[image]

Map (React):

```
  const corner1 = L.latLng(-180, -180);
  const corner2 = L.latLng(180, 180);
  const bounds = L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2);

        <Map
        ref={map => {
          this.tryToCreate(map);
        }}
        className="c-leaflet-map-map"
        center={[0, 0]}
        zoom={0}
        maxZoom={10}
        zoomControl={false}
        onzoomend={this.zoomLevelsChange}
        maxBounds={bounds}
        maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
        zoomSnap={0}
        crs={L.CRS.Simple}
      >
        <ImageOverlay
          bounds={map.backgroundImageBounds || map.bounds}
          attribution="&amp;copy TofnaTech"
          url={
            map.backgroundImage ||
            map.backgroundImageURL ||
            TransparentImage
          }
          opacity={map.opacity}
          className={cn({ transparentImage: !map.backgroundImage })}
        />
        <FeatureGroup
          ref={controller => {
            this.controller = controller;
            this.tryToCreate();
          }}
        >
          <EditControl
            position="topleft"
            onCreated={this._onCreated}
            onEditStart={this.onEditStart}
            onEditStop={this.onEditStop}
            onEdited={this.onEdited}
            draw={{
              polyline: false,
              polygon: {
                shapeOptions: { ...defaultShapeOptions }
              },
              rectangle: {
                shapeOptions: { ...defaultShapeOptions }
              },
              circle: {
                shapeOptions: { ...defaultShapeOptions }
              },
              marker: false,
              circlemarker: false
            }}
            edit={{
              remove: false
            }}
          /></Map>
```

Comment: I guess you haven't tried setting `zoomSnap` to zero?

Comment: Please edit your question to see how your map initialization works. The bits about `fitBounds` and `zoomSnap` are going to be most important; also Leaflet version. Also: how should it look like in a screen rotated 90 degrees (higher than wide)??

Comment: @IvanSanchez I've added code. Leaflet version is 1.6. It should be fit to screen. Users should see all layers at all resolutions.

Comment: Oh, React. I don't do React. Look into calling `fitBounds()` somehow instead of specifying a starting zoom level.

Comment: I dont understand when should I use fitBounds()

Comment: Once, on initialization.

Comment: Can you give an example, how this method will solve my problem, didn't get it?

Comment: See https://plnkr.co/edit/yg2EXGfEf9wH9N9ULwIp?p=preview and/or https://run.plnkr.co/preview/ck5iuek8i00051w67w6mqsvn5/

Comment: thank you for ur interest but fitbounds only zooming to giving bound. Its not providing map seem same at every resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Using React-Leaflet is a little different.  You can accomplish what you're trying to do in `componentDidMount`, where you can make a reference to your map and then call fitBounds on that.

**Edit: Adding the rectangle**

However, the next issue is resolution.  Leaflet will maintain the aspect ratio so you actually need to render your circle (or rectangle)in the corner dynamically if you always want it to show up in the bottom left corner of the screen regardless of the aspect ratio of the screen and browser.  So in `componentDidMount`, just after you set the new bounds, you can get those bounds, and define a rectangle (or anything) to always render in the same spot relative to say, the `getBounds()._southWest` bound.  In this code I wrapped this code in a `setTimeout` because the animation takes a moment and that moment needs to pass to get the new bounds values from `getBounds()`.  I'm sure there's a way to reduce or remove that animation time.

To keep the rectangle in the same spot, I wrote a `onMove` function for the map to always recalculate the position regardless of moving the map around or resizing the window.

Note that the size of the rectangle is a little slapdash in this example, but I think you'll have an easier time getting a consistent size using CRS, as CRS is a lot more uniform than lats and lngs.

```js
class Map extends React.Component {

  state = {
    rectCoords: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const map = this.mapReference.leafletElement;
    window.map = map;
    console.log("Initiates with bounds:", map.getBounds());

    map.fitBounds([[32.852169, -90.5322], [33.852169, -85.5322]]);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Bounds immediately reset to", map.getBounds());

      const rectCoords = [
        [
          map.getBounds()._southWest.lat + 0.1,
          map.getBounds()._southWest.lng + 0.1
        ],
        [
          map.getBounds()._southWest.lat + 1, 
          map.getBounds()._southWest.lng + 1
        ]
      ];

      this.setState({ rectCoords });
    }, 500);
  }

  onMapmove = () => {
    const map = this.mapReference.leafletElement;
    const rectCoords = [
      [
        map.getBounds()._southWest.lat + 0.1,
        map.getBounds()._southWest.lng + 0.1
      ],
      [map.getBounds()._southWest.lat + 1, map.getBounds()._southWest.lng + 1]
    ];

    this.setState({ rectCoords });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <LeafletMap
        ref={mapReference => this.mapReference = mapReference}
        zoom={4}
        center={[33.852169, -100.5322]}
        onMove={() => this.onMapmove() } >

        <TileLayer ... />

        {this.state.rectCoords && (
          <Rectangle
            bounds={this.state.rectCoords}
            color={"#ff7800"}
            weight={1}
          />
        )}

      </LeafletMap>
    );

  }

}
```

So even though the map initiates with certain bounds, it immediately fits it to your desired bounds, and renders the rectangle always in the bottom left corner in the same spot.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fitbounds-84tnb) is a working codesandbox.  I'm sure this can be adapted to using CRS Simple as well.

Comment: I'm already doing it with tryToCreate method and this is not about my questions seems the same in every resolution.

Comment: I realized Ithat after I posted my solution I changed some things and the codesandbox link was the wrong link.  Also I reread your question and added some code to address your issue of always rendering a rectangle / circle in the same place relative to the bottom left corner.  Does that get you closer to your desired behavior?